# Assign variable from executed SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I will be using Basic as the language and sqlite as the db. So I have 2 tables and will query one and want to use the returned results to assign to a variable to query the second table.

So I get the integar tID for the first row in table1

```
SELECT tID from table1 LIMIT 0,1
```

So I want to say

```
Dim tINT as int
tINT = tID
```

then

```
SELECT values_ from table2 WHERE tID = tINT
```

And also I will be retrieving multiple items such as

```
SELECT tID, names, folders from table1 LIMIT 0,1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ideas about what?  There's no real question here, just an outline of what you want to do.  What's the actual *problem*?  What is preventing you from moving forward?

Comment: Well I'm new to SQL for a start. So what is the format that a SELECT statement returns. I read that the last value is available. So how to I say,. SELECT tID(and tINT = tID) from table1 LIMIT 0,1.

Comment: In VBA you can use a DAO.Recordset or a ADODB.Recordset to store the resulting records.

Comment: If you're using the Basic programmng languge why is this question tagged VBA? Visual Basic for Applications is *not* Basic - that's a differnt language...